# Invoke Visualforce JavaScript function from LWC

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, community

I have included an LWC component inside a VF page through **$Lightning.createComponent**.

As per my requirement I need to call a javascript function on parent VF page on click of a button on LWC component.

my VF page:

```
<apex:page>
    <script>
        function callMe(someParam) {}       
        
        $Lightning.use("c:myApp", function() {
            $Lightning.createComponent("c:myLWCComp",
              "LightningComponentid",
              function(cmp) {
              });
        }); 
    </script>   
</apex:page>
```

my LWC Comp:

```
<template>
    <lightning-button label="Call Vf Method" onclick={callVfMethod}></lightning-button>
</template>
```

In above example. On click of "Call Vf Method" button on LWC I want to call "callMe" method on parent Visualforce page. Also I want to pass some value as parameter.

Please note that I these pages and components are accessed inside community.

Comment: You can't directly call the method, you have to fire an event. You can place parameters into the event detail object. See the Q&A I linked.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thank you so much for pointing me to the correct post. It worked perfectly.